# Why does ruby sort Alphanumeric strings with 1's and 0's as binary?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sorting, natural-sort

I have an array `["Q10", "Q100", "Q1000", "Q1000a", "Q1001", "Q98"]`. After sorting it, I get the following result:

```
['Q100', 'Q1000', 'Q1000a','Q98', 'Q10', 'Q1001'].sort
["Q10", "Q100", "Q1000", "Q1000a", "Q1001", "Q98"]
```

Because of this behaviour, I cannot sort my ActiveRecord objects correctly. I have a model of `Question` which has a field `label`. I need to sort it based on label. So Question with label `Q1` would be first and the question with label `Q1a` would follow and so on. I get in a similar order with ActiveRecord described to the above example of array. I am using postgresql as my database.

Now I have 3 questions.

1. Why alphanumeric string sorting behave that way?
2. How can I achieve my required sorting without using the sort block?
3. How can I achieve that sorting in ActiveRecord?

Comment: What label patterns / formats exist?

Comment: @stefan. It’s only in the following format: letter then number and then may or may not be a letter.

Comment: And you want to sort each part separately? i.e. alphabetically by leading letter, then numerically by number, then again alphabetically by trailing letter (if present)

Comment: We can ignore the letter in my case. Cary has answered the question in a lot of detail. It not only solves my problem but any other problem that could occur with my pattern. Please have a look.

Comment: I saw Cary's answers, it's great (as usual). But you specifically asked for a solution _"without using the sort block"_ and _"sorting in ActiveRecord"_ – did your requirements change?

Comment: Sort of, because before I was looking for a solution that would give me the required result with a database query. Later I realised that I don’t have a lot of data and it wouldn’t hurt in my case to be a little inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your array were

```
arr = ["Q10", "Q100", "Q1000", "Q8", "Q1001", "Q98"]
```

you could write

```
arr.sort_by { |s| s[/\d+/].to_i }
  #=> ["Q8", "Q10", "Q98", "Q100", "Q1000", "Q1001"]
```

If

```
s = "Q1000"
```

then

```
s[/\d+/].to_i
  #=> 1000
```

See [Enumerable#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) and [String#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

The regular expression `/\d+/` matches a substring of `s` that contains one or more digits.

---

If the array were

```
arr = ["Q10b", "Q100", "Q1000", "Q10a", "Q1001", "Q98", "Q10c"]
```

you could write

```
arr.sort_by { |s| [s[/\d+/].to_i, s[/\D+\z/]] }
  #=> ["Q10a", "Q10b", "Q10c", "Q98", "Q100", "Q1000", "Q1001"]
```

If

```
s = "Q10b"
```

then

```
[s[/\d+/].to_i, s[/\D+\z/]]
  #=> [10, "b"]
```

The regular expression `/\D+\z/` matches a substring of `s` that contains one or more non-digits at the end (`\z`) of the string.

See [Array#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E), specifically the third paragraph, for an explanation of how arrays are ordered when sorting.

---

If the array were

```
arr = ["Q10b", "P100", "Q1000", "PQ10a", "Q1001", "Q98", "Q10c"]
```

you could write

```
arr.sort_by { |s| [s[/\A\D+/], s[/\d+/].to_i, s[/\D+\z/]] }
  #=> ["P100", "PQ10a", "Q10b", "Q10c", "Q98", "Q1000", "Q1001"]
```

If

```
s = "PQ10a"
```

then

```
[s[/\A\D+/], s[/\d+/].to_i, s[/\D+\z/]]
  #=> ["PQ", 10, "a"]
```

The regular expression `/\A\D+/` matches a substring of `s` that contains one or more non-digits at the beginning (`\A`) of the string.

Comment: `arr.sort_by { |s| s.split(/(\d+)/).each_slice(2).flat_map { |a, n| [a, n.to_i] } }` is more general, though perhaps less readable :)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick for you, casting them to numbers before sorting.

```
['100', '1000', '98', '10', '1001'].map(&:to_i).sort
```

---

*This strange `map(&:to_i)` is shorthand for `map { |x| x.to_i }`*

Edit:

You could do this with AR. This will throw an error if the column doesn't contain a number disguised as a string.

```
Model.order("some_column::integer")
```

Edit II:

Try this if it contains strings as well.

```
Model.order("cast(some_column as integer))"
```